# "Da geht mir die Pumpe"

Tags: meaning

Könnten Ihr mir bitte erklären, was der Ausdruck *Da geht mir die Pumpe* bedeutet? Aus dem Kontext vermute ich, es könnte etwas mit Angst zu tun haben, aber ich bin mir nicht ganz sicher, ob ich damit richtig liege. Ist mit "Pumpe" etwa der Herzschlag gemeint?

Comment: Ich denke, dass der Herzschlag höchstwahrscheinlich gemeint ist, aber ich wüsste gerne, wo du diesen Ausdruck schon mal gehört hast.

Comment: Der Herzschlag wäre "das Pumpen".

Comment: Nico, ich sah diesen Satz in einer DaF-Aufgabe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Die „Pumpe“ ist ein umgangssprachlicher Begriff für das Herz in diesem Kontext: das Herz pumpt Blut, deshalb Pumpe.

Wenn die Pumpe geht, dann heisst das: das Herz schlägt.

Der Ausspruch „Da geht mir die Pumpe“ betont dabei die Tatsache, dass ich etwas wahrnehme, was eigentlich normal ist: die Pumpe geht / das Herz schlägt. In diesem Kontext bedeutet das, dass das Herz besonders schnell/stark schlägt.

Typischerweise wird der Ausdruck benutzt, wenn man sich entweder erschrickt, ängstigt oder besonders aufregt, denn dann „geht“ das Herz besonders schnell. Aber auch nach sportlicher Anstrengung kann mir „die Pumpe gehen“.

Wenn man es aber damit übertreibt, dann kann es sein, dass man in Ohnmacht fällt... dann ist alles halb so schlimm, wenn der herbeigeeilte Kumpel den Puls fühlt und sagen kann: „Kein Problem, die Pumpe geht noch“

Comment: Ist das 'ne regionale Geschichte? Ich kann zwar die Erklärung nachvollziehen, habe es aber noch nie gehört.

Comment: Möglich. Für mich (Süddeutschland) gehört das so zum normalen Sprachgebrauch, dass ich nichtmal drüber nachdenken musste....

Comment: Interessant! Für mich als "Rheinländer" wäre der Ausruck einfacher nachzuvollziehen in der Version: "Mir geht die Pumpe abba sowatt von hoch, wenn ich sehe..."

Comment: Ich hab's überregional gehört

Comment: Mir als Berliner geht es da wie Nico: Erklärung logisch nachvollziehbar, Formulierung nie gehört

Comment: Pumpe könnte aber - gerade beim Sport - auch die Luftpumpe bedeuten, alias die Lunge. Die geht allerdings gewöhnlich mit der Blutpumpe synchron.

Comment: nein, Pumpe hat- zumindest meiner Erfahrung nach- nix mit der Lunge zu tun

Comment: In Mitteldeutschland ist Pumpe als Synonym für Herz auch gebräuchlich.

Comment: @userunknown rein logisch richtig aber ich würde sagen das Herz hat sich da als "pumpe" bereits eingebürgert. Ich bin aus nordwest Deutschland und auch hier ist das ein gängiger Spruch. Auch wird sowas gesagt wie "die Pumpe giebt den Geist auf" oder so, wenn jemand z.B. Herzprobleme hat.

Comment: Man vergeliche auch mit dem Ausdruck "pumperlg'sund" (so gesund, dass das Herz angemessen kräftig schlägt?), der offenbar im Süden gebräuchlich ist und es in letzter Zeit im Zushg. mit den Corona-Virus in Pressemeldungen geschaft hat.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ich halte das für einen etymologischen falschen Freund; ich denke, dass pumperlgsund nichts mit der Pumpe am Hut hat. Ich konnte allerdings keine Belege in irgendeiner Richtung finden.